# Running Tasks from a list

Tags: c#, task

When I run this code, I get an exception that I don't understand: "start may not be called on a continuation task". Please show me what am I doing wrong.

```
  List<Task> TasksList = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ThreadsNumber; i++)
        {
            int local = i;
            var task = new Task<List<string>>(() => PrimeTask(Ratio * local, (local + 1) * Ratio))
                .ContinueWith((t) => UpdatePrimesList(t.Result));
            TasksList.Add(task);
            TasksList[i].Start();
        }

        Task.WaitAny(TasksList.ToArray());
```

Comment: What language is this? Tag the question with the language.

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Comment: take a look at this `MSDN posting` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288.aspx

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is that `task` is not referring to the first task you're creating, but to the one you create with `ContinueWith`.

Ie. this construction:

```
var task = new Task<..>(...).ContinueWith(...);
```

will reference the task that `ContinueWith` returns. You no longer have a reference to the first task.

It's basically the same as this:

```
var task = new SomeObject().SomeMethodReturningAnotherObject();
```

Here you no longer have a reference to `SomeObject`, just a reference to whatever the method `SomeMethodReturningAnotherObject` does return.

Instead do this:

```
var task = new Task<..>(...);
task.ContinueWith(...);
TaskList.Add(task);
task.Start();
```

This will correctly start the first task, and not attempt to start the continuation task, as your exception message is telling you.